# Creating SMS Gateway using asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I m trying to implement my own SMS gateway using asp.net MVC. Please suggest any solution how to start with it.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/francissvk/asp-net-how-to-send-sms-from-my-web-application/

Comment: Thanks Dhiren for your reply but i don't want to use any 3rd party API for it i want to create my own.Please suggest